# How to make a closed accordion tab open an external url when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I'm using the JelleKralt Responsive tabs at https://github.com/jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs on this design: http://www.sitesellprosdesign.com/demo.html

I need some of the tabs to open an external url and was successfully able to do so using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a[href^="#tab-4"]').on('click', function(event) { 
  window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
  });
    </script>
```

However, when the tabs switch to accordion, the redirect does not work.  I need a way to make the accordion titles open an external url when clicked as well.

Any help would be most appreciated.  I'm not at all versed in javascript/jQuery so I'm winging it here.

Comment: Where on the page that you provided (demo.html) are the tabs in question? I searched the source code for `tab-4` but didn't find any matches. Additionally, the source code only contained two instances of `<a href="#`. The jQuery you posted applies only to `<a>` tags whose `href` attribute begins with `#tab-4`. Edit: I was redirected to `pros.sitesell.com` when following the link you posted. Is that where the link is supposed to lead?

Comment: So sorry, typo in the url.  The code posted is correct and effective for the tabs.  It doesn't work in accordion mode though.  The tabs are at the top of the page and the link to the demo page has been amended. The tab attributes aren't carried through to the accordion mode, which is why it won't work.  I'm just not sure what to do to make it work in accordion mode.  I'm just helping out a friend who's developer quit on him.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: When you say "accordian mode", where on the page are the elements that you're referring to? Are you talking about the links at the bottom of the page in the gray div?

Comment: No, I'm talking about the 4 tabbed sections at the top - it's a responsive tab to accordion jquery plugin from github available at the link provided above.  There is a bit of documentation there and if you reduce the browser window below 767px, you'll see they go to accordion mode rather than responsive tabs.

What I need help with is making the accordion titles clickable to external links like I did for when they're displayed as tabs on a desktop screen resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be that your click event gets unbound as elements are recreated for the new layout (accordian). Try with a more sustainable bind:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href="#tab-4"]', function() { 
   window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
});
```